# Windows 10 Account permissions

Tags: windows-10, permissions

I have just upgraded my daughters laptop to Windows 10 and set up family controls. However there are 2 fundamental issues with this.

1. If she removes herself from the family she then gains full control over when / what she can access. I've dealt with this by denying access to account.microsoft.com in the hosts file (which needs an admin password to change)
2. If she changes to a local account, all family account settings associated with the Microsoft account are ignored.

My question is, using group policies (or any other method) is there a way to remove this option from her settings panel?

Comment: do you have a domain setup?

Comment: No just a normal home set up, it's my daughters laptop and I just want a bit of control over it, which was possible with the Parental controls on Win 8.